# Receiving syntax error in python shell, code works in python command prompt

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am receiving a syntax error in python IDLE shell 3.12.0, the "f" in "for" is highlighted red and it says SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

The code works in python command prompt, why is it receiving an error in the shell?

```
def sequence(c):
    z = 0
    while True:
        yield z
        z = z ** 2 + c

for n, z in enumerate(sequence(c=1)):
    print(f"z({n}) = {z}")
    if n >= 9:
        break
```

I haven't tried anything other than adding a space or tab. Code works in python command prompt.

Comment: This is a rare case where a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Have you saved the code as a file and try to load it from IDLE, or do you enter the code directly in the IDLE shell?